# Injectivity/Complex Mapping

Tags: complex-analysis

In $\mathbb{C}$, consider the neighborhood $O$ $:=$ {${x+iy; (x+1)^2 + (y-1)^2 < 4}$}. Show that $w=z^2$ is not one-to-one when its domain of definition is restricted to $O$.

I'm not sure where to start since I don't think I properly understand how the domain of definition works for maps. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This means "show there are two points of $O$ ('two $z$ values') that are sent to the same value (i.e., 'same $w$-value'). Since $z^2  = (-z)^2$, one way to do this is to show that some point $z$ and its negative are both in $O$. Drawing a picture of $O$ should help.